# How to mock Sequelize with Jest?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, sequelize.js

I am trying to write unit tests for code which makes calls to Sequelize to create a database.

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to mock out calls to Sequelize such that I can assert they have created the database tables correctly.

My code which hits Sequelize is as follows:

```js
import { Sequelize, DataTypes } from "sequelize";

export setup_db = async (db_path: string) => {
    //Get read/write connection to database
    const sequelizeContext = new Sequelize({
      dialect: "sqlite",
      storage: db_path,
    });

    //Check if connection is secure, throw error if not
    try {
      await sequelizeContext.authenticate();
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }

    //Define first table
    const Table1 = sequelizeContext.define(
      "table1",
      {
        fieldName_1: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING
        }
      },
      { tableName: "table1" }
    );

    //Define second table
    const Table2 = sequelizeContext.define(
      "table2", 
      {
        fieldName_1: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
      {tablename: "table2"}
    });

    //Define relationship between tables... each Gamertag hasMany wzMatches
    Table1.hasMany(Table2);

    await Table1.sync();
    await Table2.sync();
  };
```

Ideally, I would like to assert that `define` was called properly, `hasMany` was called properly, and `sync` was called for each database.

My test code currently is as follows, although it throws an error about

> Cannot spy the authenticate property because it is not a function; undefined given instead.

```js
import { setup_db } from "../../core/dataManager";
const Sequelize = require("sequelize").Sequelize;

describe("DataManager.setup_db", () => {
  it("should call sequelize to correctly set up databases", async () => {
    //Arrange
    const authenticateSpy = jest.spyOn(Sequelize, "authenticate");

    //Act
    await setup_db("path/to/db.db");

    //Assert
    expect(authenticateSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

I'm not sure if `spyOn` is the right method to call, or whether I can/how I can use `jest.mock` to mock out and inspect calls to `Sequelize`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am going to use [jest.mock(moduleName, factory, options)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) to mock `sequelize` module manually.

Unit test solution:

`index.ts`:

```js
import { Sequelize, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';

export const setup_db = async (db_path: string) => {
  const sequelizeContext = new Sequelize({
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    storage: db_path,
  });

  try {
    await sequelizeContext.authenticate();
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }

  const Table1 = sequelizeContext.define(
    'table1',
    {
      fieldName_1: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
      },
    },
    { tableName: 'table1' },
  );

  const Table2 = sequelizeContext.define(
    'table2',
    {
      fieldName_1: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
      },
    },
    { tableName: 'table2' },
  );

  (Table1 as any).hasMany(Table2);

  await Table1.sync();
  await Table2.sync();
};
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import { setup_db } from './';
import { Sequelize, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils';

jest.mock('sequelize', () => {
  const mSequelize = {
    authenticate: jest.fn(),
    define: jest.fn(),
  };
  const actualSequelize = jest.requireActual('sequelize');
  return { Sequelize: jest.fn(() => mSequelize), DataTypes: actualSequelize.DataTypes };
});

const mSequelizeContext = new Sequelize();

describe('64648688', () => {
  afterAll(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  it('should setup db correctly', async () => {
    const mTable1 = { hasMany: jest.fn(), sync: jest.fn() };
    const mTable2 = { sync: jest.fn() };
    mocked(mSequelizeContext.define).mockImplementation((modelName): any => {
      switch (modelName) {
        case 'table1':
          return mTable1;
        case 'table2':
          return mTable2;
      }
    });
    await setup_db(':memory:');
    expect(Sequelize).toBeCalledWith({ dialect: 'sqlite', storage: ':memory:' });
    expect(mSequelizeContext.authenticate).toBeCalled();
    expect(mSequelizeContext.define).toBeCalledWith(
      'table1',
      {
        fieldName_1: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
        },
      },
      { tableName: 'table1' },
    );
    expect(mSequelizeContext.define).toBeCalledWith(
      'table2',
      {
        fieldName_1: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
        },
      },
      { tableName: 'table2' },
    );
    expect(mTable1.hasMany).toBeCalledWith(mTable2);
    expect(mTable1.sync).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(mTable2.sync).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/64648688/index.test.ts (16.442s)
  64648688
    ✓ should setup db correctly (11ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |    91.67 |      100 |      100 |    90.91 |                   |
 index.ts |    91.67 |      100 |      100 |    90.91 |                12 |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        20.184s
```

Comment: I do find that in the example you provided, if I have another test case, I am not able to have two different behaviors. See my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76039291/mock-sequelize-authenticate-in-typescript-project