# how can I reimplement a Mock function of a manually mocked module?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, sequelize.js

I am working in a test module for my application which uses Sequelize to make queries to a database. I am trying to mock this module and I found this answer which was oriented to typescript: [How to mock Sequelize with Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64648688/how-to-mock-sequelize-with-jest)

I am doing my test in javascript and I find the mocked function isn't working. So I would like to find an alternative to call the function member of a mocked module inside a test block and perform an implementation of it. I'm not sure if it is a good practice, but I didn't find another way to test the procedure, so I require to reimplement the member definition, however when I run the test, it appears as the reimplementation wasn't performed.

The function I was intended to test is in file `sql-api.js`

```
const initDB = async function () {
  await connect()
  await synchronizePatients()

};

const sequelize = new Sequelize(config.db.database, config.db.username, config.db.password, {
  host: config.db.host,
  dialect: 'postgres'
});

const connect = async function () {
  try {
    return await sequelize.authenticate();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error);
    return error;
  }
}

const synchronizePatients = async function () {
  console.log("Synchronize patients")
  return await Patients.sync({ alter: true })
}

const Patients = sequelize.define('patients', {
  uuid: {
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull: false,
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4 // Or Sequelize.UUIDV1
  },
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  },
  nombres: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  apellidos: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
}, {
  // Other model options go here
  timestamps: true,
});
```

Then I have a mock module in `__mock__` folder, named `sequelized.js`

```
'use strict';

const sequelize = jest.createMockFromModule('sequelize');


const mSequelize = {
    authenticate: jest.fn(),
    define: jest.fn()
  };
  
const actualSequelize = jest.requireActual('sequelize');

sequelize.Sequelize = jest.fn(() => mSequelize);
sequelize.DataTypes = actualSequelize.DataTypes;

module.exports= sequelize;
```

Then  in my test code in `__tests__` folder:

```
const sqlapi = require("../sql-api");
const { Sequelize, Op } = require('sequelize');
const config = require("../config.json")

const mPatients = { sync: jest.fn() };
const mUsers = {
  sync: jest.fn(),
  findOne: jest.fn(),
  create: jest.fn()
  };


jest.mock("sequelize");

const mSequelizeContext = new Sequelize();

describe("Testing setup DB", () => {
  afterAll(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  test("It should connect correctly", async () => {


    mSequelizeContext.define.mockImplementation((modelName) => {
      switch (modelName) {
        case 'patients':
          return mPatients;
        case 'users':
          return mUsers;
      }
    })

    await sqlapi.initDB();

    expect(Sequelize).toBeCalledWith(config.db.database, config.db.username, config.db.password, {
      host: config.db.host,
      dialect: 'postgres'
    });

    expect(mSequelizeContext.authenticate).toBeCalled();

  })
})
```

However, when I try to run the code, I have the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'sync' of undefined

      374 | const synchronizePatients = async function () {
      375 |   console.log("Synchronize patients")
    > 376 |   return await Patients.sync({ alter: true })
          |                         ^
      377 | }
```

As the function define wasn't reimplemented in `mSequelizeContext.define.mockImplementation(...)`. I don't know why it doesn't work. In the example I referred first, to call the mocked function they use a `mocked(mSequelizeContext.define)`, however, that `mocked` function is part of another library `ts-jest/utils` oriented to typescript. I was wondering that in Javascript it isn't needed.

I also noticed that  replacing the implementation in the mock folder by:

```
const mSequelize = {
    authenticate: jest.fn(),
    define: jest.fn().mockImplementation((modelName) => {
      switch (modelName) {
        case 'patients':
          return mPatients;
        case 'users':
          return mUsers;
      }
    })
  };
```

And here it works, but by the other way, reimplementing inside the test procedure, it doesn't.

Please, if you could orient me in this implementation.

Comment: It would be somehow easier if you would do some isolated tests. Anyhow it's not the subject. From where is `Patients` coming? Can you show the import statement? `Patients` might be an entity but since `Sequelize` is mocked the entity cannot be generated, so you would have to mock as well `Patients` with the `sync` method.

Comment: Sure, I've just added the part of `Patients` model definition. I also mocked that model as you see in the test file. However, as I also mentioned  when I tried to reimplement the jest function of `define` inside the test procedure, it appears that this line isn't taken into account.

Comment: Why are you calling `await sqlapi.initDB();` before `mockImplementation`?

Comment: As I say in my first comment, if you would isolate your tests, it would be much easier. You are trying to test multiple thing at the same time and this make thing much more complicated and difficult to maintain. Of course it is up to you to do it like this but you have to be very cautious in the way you are mocking your functions. So first be sure you mocked all your functions, before to instanciate `await sqlapi.initDB();`

Comment: Sorry, it was a lapsus, as I was trying several times, I do not notice that order. In fact, I probed first calling the `mockImplementation` and then the `sqlapi.initDB()` but it isn't working and I don't know why the `mockImplementation` function is not being applied to the define member of the manually mocked `sequelize` module.